# failing scipy.minimize for multiple constraints

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to minimize the following function using scipy.minimize

```
def lower_bound(x, mu, r, sigma):
    mu_h = mu_hat(x, mu, r)
    sigma_h = sigma_hat(x, sigma)
    gauss = np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(10)
    return (1 + mu_h + math.sqrt(2) * sigma_h * min(gauss[1]))
```

all the involved function are tested and return values as expected. Now for setting up the minimization process, I defined

```
cons = ({"type": "ineq",
             "fun": mu_hat,
             "args": (mu, r)},
            {"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x, sigma: -1.0*sigma_hat(x, sigma),
             "args": (sigma)},
            {"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x: x},
            {"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x: 1-np.dot(np.ones(x.size), x)})
```

as the constraints. When I run this code scipy.minimize gives me the following error message for the constraints:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 312, in <listcomp>
    mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['ineq']]))
TypeError: <lambda>() argument after * must be an iterable, not float
```

what is not correct with the defined constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

```
mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['ineq']]))
TypeError: <lambda>() argument after * must be an iterable, not float
```

So we can infer that `c['args']` is of type `float`, because `c['args']` is the only variable with `*` applied to it.  Clearly the lookup of `'args'` in `c` has succeeded, so we know that `c` is a `float` where an iterable (list, tuple, etc.) was expected.

If we now look at your constraints, the `args` passed are `(mu, r)` in one case and `(sigma)` in the other.  The problem is clear now: `(sigma)` is equivalent to `sigma`, and is not a tuple.  To make a 1-tuple in Python, you must say `(sigma,)`.